# JQuery .show("slow") not rendering elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some basic JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.opening-message a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".opening-message").hide();
    $(".message-one").show("slow");
    $(".reply-one").delay(1000).show("slow");
    $(".message-options").delay(2000).show("fast", "easing");
  });

  $('.level-three-message a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".level-one-message").hide();
    $(".level-two-message").hide();
    $(".level-three-message").hide();
    $(".stage-one-message-level-three").show("slow");
    $(".stage-one-reply-level-three").delay(1000).show("slow");
  });
```

}

My HTML DOM is below, please excuse the length of it. As you can see below, the enclosing div is already visible, but the divs within it display when I remove the "slow" arguments, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <div class="message-area">
    <div class="reply-one-lvl-one" style="display:none">
      <%= @stage_one_messages_level_one %>
    </div>

    <div class="reply-one-lvl-two" style="display:none">
      <%= @stage_one_messages_level_two %>
    </div>

    <div class="reply-one-lvl-three" style="display:none">
      <%= @stage_one_messages_level_three %>
    </div>

    <div class="opening-message">
      <p>Press hello to get started</p>
      <a href=''>
          <%= @first_message.text %>
      </a>
    </div>

      <div class="message-options" style="display:none">

      <p class="message-options-intro">Now choose your reply. Make it good!</p>

      <div class="level-one-message">
        <a href="">
          <%= @stage_two_message_level_one.text %>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="level-two-message">
        <a href="">
          <%= @stage_two_message_level_two.text %>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="level-three-message">
        <a href="">
          <%= @stage_two_message_level_three.text %>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="chat-area">
    <div class="message message-one speech-bubble-message" style="display:none">
      <p><%= @first_message.text %></p>
    </div>

    <div class="message reply-one speech-bubble-reply" style="display:none">
      <p><%= @first_reply.text %></p>
    </div>

    <div class="message stage-one-message-level-three speech-bubble-message" style="display:none">
      <p><%= @stage_one_message_level_three.text %></p>
    </div>

    <div class="message stage-one-reply-level-three speech-bubble-reply" style="display:none">
      <p><%= @stage_one_reply_level_three.text %></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

The first set of `.show("slow")` in `$('.opening-message a')` work fine, but the ones within the `$('.level-three-message a')` do not work. Any idea why this might be? They both render when I remove the slow arguments.

Comment: Is it possible there is a parent element that is invisible? Can you show your html?

Comment: Can you please reproduce the issue with a jsfiddle ?

Comment: please show us your HTML DOM

Comment: Have added the HTML DOM thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the word `"easing"`, it's invalid - you have to tell it the type of `easing`, eg `"swing"`

change:

```
$(".message-options").delay(2000).show("fast", "easing");
```

to, for example

```
$(".message-options").delay(2000).show("fast",  "swing");
```

[Here's a fiddle showing it working](https://jsfiddle.net/13q160gg/)

Comment: Perfect. So the argument "easing" was making later arguments not work right?

Comment: Yeah that's right - always look in your console if something breaks, it will tell you what is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to stop using the word 'slow', it means 600ms. I also note you are using delay, I recommend changing this to use complete functions. Like this:

```
$(".opening-message").hide();
$(".message-one").show("slow");
$(".reply-one").delay(1000).show("slow");
$(".message-options").delay(2000).show("fast", "easing");
```

becomes

```
    $(".opening-message").hide( 0, function() {
        $(".message-one").show( 600, function() {
            $(".reply-one").show( 600, function() {
                $(".message-options").show( 200, "linear");
            });
        });
    });
```

Like this you can have it all in order, when one completes the other starts.

I also put your code into a fiddle and the .show('slow') was working with jQuery 2.x

All the info you need here: http://api.jquery.com/show/